# how to both Compress and Minify content together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, compression, gzipstream, minify, deflatestream

i know we can compress response by declaring Response.Filter as GZip or Delfalte streams, but how i can perform both compression and minification together? declaring new class that inherits Stream, then first performing minify on content, then compress that by GZip or Deflate depending on User-Agent supported each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm... 2 days and nothing. check out Mads Kristensen approach http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx. however this isn't exactly that i want but is better than nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

For javascript & css files, you can minify them using [Microsoft Ajax Minifier 4.0](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584).
You can also use  [Microsoft Ajax Minifier as a Build Task](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx).

For response compression, you are on the right way, you can use Response.Filter and use either GZip or Delfalte streams.
For a sample code for using Response.Filter, refer to the following article [Combining, Compressing, Minifying ASP.NET ScriptResource and HTML Markups](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetOptimizer.aspx).

Also, you can use IIS to compress content.

- [IIS6 Compression](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html)
- [IIS7 Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003(WS.10).aspx)